# Crash on libswiftCore impossible to reproduce

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, crash, crash-reports

I am having an issue, some small (few %) of our user are crashing on our app with the following trace :

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100ae3740 _TTSfq4n_s_n_n_n___TFs17_assertionFailureFTVs12StaticStringSS4fileS_4lineSu5flagsVs6UInt32_Os5Never + 164
1  OMGRedesign                    0x100171f88 specialized DataManager.userLoggingState() -> DataManager.LoggingUserState (DataManager.swift)
2  OMGRedesign                    0x10011e59c specialized APIManager.(login(String, password : String, success : () -> ()?, failure : (Error?) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) (APIManager.swift)
3  OMGRedesign                    0x10012b0d0 partial apply for APIManager.(loginUsingStoredTokens(String, success : () -> ()?, failure : (Error?) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) + 4295897296
4  p2_OAuth2                      0x1008ea38c _TMaC9p2_OAuth210OAuth2Base + 720
5  p2_OAuth2                      0x1008ea1e0 _TMaC9p2_OAuth210OAuth2Base + 292
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x18ebb29a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18ebc37a8 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 304
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18ebb29a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18ebb75e8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 996
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18fca90c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18fca6cdc __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18fbd6d94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
13 GraphicsServices               0x191640074 GSEventRunModal + 100
14 UIKit                          0x195e8f130 UIApplicationMain + 208
15 OMGRedesign                    0x1000d3ab8 main (Item.swift:129)
16 libdyld.dylib                  0x18ebe559c start + 4
```

The following code is this

```
func userLoggingState() -> LoggingUserState {

    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard as UserDefaults

    let isRegularUserLogged = userDefault.bool(forKey:"regular-user-logged")
    let regularUserName = userDefault.string(forKey: "regular-user-username")
    let dummyDefaultUser = userDefault.string(forKey: "default-dummy-user")

    if isRegularUserLogged == false &&
       (regularUserName == nil || regularUserName?.isEmpty == true) &&
       (dummyDefaultUser == nil || dummyDefaultUser?.isEmpty == true) {
        return .None
    }
    else if isRegularUserLogged == true &&
        (regularUserName != nil && regularUserName?.isEmpty == false) &&
        (dummyDefaultUser == nil || dummyDefaultUser?.isEmpty == true) {
        return .Regular
    }
    else if isRegularUserLogged == false &&
        (regularUserName == nil || regularUserName?.isEmpty == true) &&
        (dummyDefaultUser != nil && dummyDefaultUser?.isEmpty == false) {
        return .Dummy
    }
    else {
        PLogWarning("userLogging is in an invalid state, returning None")
        return .None
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this might crash and since I cannot reproduce it, it's very difficult to figure it out.

One very strange things though on the crash report is this line :

```
15 OMGRedesign                    0x1000d3ab8 main (Item.swift:129)
```

Item.swift is a CoreData NSManagedObject derived class. Why is it mentioning there?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have any previous version of the app that stored a string in "regular-user-logged" and not a bool?

Comment: No this flag was never used on previous versions

Comment: I'm getting the same error from some users, and not able to reproduce it either. Did you find out anything?

Comment: @FerranMaylinch  yes i just answered my own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this error in our code was triggered by a "fatalError" command.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Can you elaborate on that answer? Were you calling `fatalError("some message")` from `DataManager.userLoggingState()`? I have some `fatalError` calls in the class is giving me the error, but it's not inside the method that the stack trace shows, so I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, in a do-catch block I was triggering fatal error for some core data states that should never happen. So just check in ur code if u dont have this somewhere.

Comment: I've found a case where I trigger the `fatalError()` call (due to a mistake I made) so it's quite probable that in my case the error is also caused by a call to `faltalError()`. Thanks! (BTW, Apple could be more helpful, I'd like to see my fatalError message on the stack trace!) :(